# Need to Find and Count given variable in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

Hello I would be grateful if anyone could provide solution for the following problem that I have:
I need to find if given variable exists in Array;

```
var arr = new Array(4, 1, 4, 1, 4)  
var number = 4;  
var number_two = 1;
```

**is there a way to count how many times "var number" exists in "arr" and what are the indexes of this number in Array;**
Thanks,

Comment: Yes. Iterate, compare each element, increase counter.

Answer (score 1):

For counter use the following solution. In order to transform results to indices you can read more about JavaScript arrays (for instance).

```
function counter(arr, what) {
    var how_many = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == what) how_many++;
    }
    return how_many;
}

console.log(counter([4, 1, 4, 1, 4], 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to fix the other answer I'll answer it myself:

```
function counter(arr, what) {
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === what)
            indexes.push(i);
    }
    alert(indexes.length); // how many
    alert(indexes);        // indexes
}

counter([4, 1, 4, 1, 4], 4);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/9swBw/)

Answer (score 1):

It should resolve your issue.

```
var myArray = [ 10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60 ] ;

function Counter( myArray ) {
   var myBlocks = new Object ;

   for( var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) {
      var aBlock = myArray[i] ;
      if(myBlocks.hasOwnProperty(aBlock)) {
         myBlocks[aBlock]++ ;
      } else {
         myBlocks[aBlock] = 1 ;
      }
   }

   var str = "";
   for(var j in myBlocks ) {
      str += "\t Element " + j+ " : apears "+ myBlocks[j] + " time(s)\n" ;
   }
   alert( str ) ;
}

Counter(myArray);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3APY/1/)

Comment: So much code for such a simple task...

Comment: @gdoron We made different implementations. You have made a function to find specific element count in array. I've made a function to find count of all elements in array and added functionality to show my results.

Comment: @EugeneTrofimenko Following your logic, I could name +100 useful modifications of the code :)

Comment: Guys thank you all, I solved my problem. Sorry if I am beginner in JavaScript, I couldn't even imagine that my dull question would provoke this kind of contest between mega BRAINS :D

Comment: @VisioN it's a good idea for new startup :)